# How do I delete my Experts Exchange account?

Tags: account-management, experts-exchange

Many years ago, I created a free account with Experts Exchange.  It has been very useful over the years.  Recently they changed to a different model that required subscriptions, and I was no longer "grandfathered" in.

While I could have my employer pay for it, with the Stack Exchange network, there is no need.  Why pay for an inferior product when Stack Overflow and Programmers are much, much better and are free? I know I'm not the only one to have abandoned that service.

Does anyone know how to delete my account without having to spend half an hour on the phone with these people?

I know I can change my email settings, but I would like to just delete my account and I can't find any reference on their website about deleting an account.

**Update** 
After posting the message a moderator replied

> *Your account will not be billed, but is still "active", as EE does not
>   have deleted/deactivated accounts. You can return anytime to further
>   use it, within the restrictions you have as non-paying member.*

So I just changed my email preferences. I was never, and will never be a paying memeber.

Comment: I never pay either.  I just answer a couple of questions a month there and maintain free membership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago, an Experts Exchange user asked how to delete his account on [experts-exchange.com](http://www.experts-exchange.com), and the following answers were posted:

- You need to post your question in the following link:

  http://support.experts-exchange.com/
- You need to post a 0-point note in Community Support board and ask an
  EE Admin to delete the account. Community Support link is in
  the left menu.

Comment: @Andrew Neely: You're welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately that advice is incorrect. EE never fully deletes an account.  They can lock it down and prevent any email from reaching you but the account always exists.